# spring boot autoconfiguration include

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way to include autoconfigurations based on profiles? (It would be nice if there was a `spring.autonfigure.include`)

I would like to connect to an h2 database for testing and for local development. For ease of development, I would like `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class`, `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class`, and `DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class` autoconfigured. However, I would like to be able to easily switch to an oracle database which is defined in the application server and configured in a Configuration class. When switching to the oracle database, I need to exclude the autoconfiguration classes above:

```
// This only works for the oracle database - need to include autoconfig
// classes for h2 database
@SpringBootApplication(
     exclude = {
       DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
       HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
       DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class },
     scanBasePackages = {
       "foo.bar"
     })
```

I have an "h2" profile that configures the h2 database and several other profiles in which I want the live database (local, dev, test, qual, prod). I could use the `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` property on each of the live database profiles, but sometimes I want to switch between "live" and h2 databases locally. I could also figure out exactly what the excluded autoconfigure classes are doing and manually configure in an "h2" profile but I'd rather not duplicate effort.

Anyone have ideas as to how to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried splitting up `@SpringBootApplication` and having specific configurations annotated with `@Profile`? And are you aware that just changing `spring.datasource.url` should do what you need?

Comment: Why would you need to disable the autoconfig when connecting to oracle? Just provide an `application-prod.properties` and configure the Oracle datasource in there. Also you don't need to exclude auto configuration if you provide your own instances, Spring Boot is smart enough to detect the presence of a `DataSource` and act upon that. But as said just create a different `application.properties` and let spring boot decide which one to load based on the profiles.

Comment: I was able to split up the `@SpringBootApplication` and get this to work correctly. The application server (JBoss) configures the datasource so I have to configure the datasource through a configuration class. I need to disable the transaction management as I need to use JBoss' when connecting to oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by splitting up the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation and providing specific `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"foo.bar"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

For the h2 database, I enable the "h2" profile and use this class:

```
@Profile("h2")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class H2Config {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
        registration.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

And for the "live" oracle database, I disable the "h2" profile and use this class:

```
@Profile("!h2")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
public class NonH2Config {

}
```